# spring boot admin disable specific tabes from UI

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I want to disable specific tabs from Spring boot admin UI.
Is there any way to achieve this ? might be using some property or anything.
My SBA server properties are as follows :

```
spring.boot.admin.context-path=/admin
spring.boot.admin.ui.title=Admin
server.address=localhost
server.port=6789
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=Admin123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable those endpoints in your applications

Comment: can you please tell me the properties that can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

As @joshiste pointed out you have to configure your applications not spring boot admin itself.

**Warning be careful what endpoints you expose!!**

You can configure which tabs/endpoints are displayed by setting the properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include
```

You can specify a comma separated list select from {health, info, metrics, etc.}

For a fuller list @see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints