# How to customize Spring Boot admin 2.o UI?

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

How to customize Spring Admin 2.0 UI? I want to add some new tabs and delete some of the Info on the Admin screen.

Comment: An Example of Adding new custom tab : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53462345/1131967

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301232/spring-boot-admin-disable-specific-tabes-from-ui) to disable tab you should disable specific endpoint.

To add custom view check their reference documentation, you will need to implement Vue.js component:
http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#customizing-custom-views